# WSO2 Identity Server authentication with SessionID

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a website that will have a GUI where user enter username/password then this website will send the credentials through a webservice to WSO2 Identity Server.

I was thinking of using the "Login" operation of the "AuthenticationAdmin" service. However, I would like the "LoginResponse" of this service to also return a sessionID and not just true/false.

Can somebody please tell me if I am on the right path?

If not, could somebody guide me on how I could accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The login method actually returns a session cookie but it's not in the response body, it's in the headers. Take a look at the following blog post [here](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html).
After calling login() method you could get the cookie from the service context like this:

```
(String) authstub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getProperty(  
  HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING);
```

and then use it for additional calls.

Comment: Do you have a recent example on how I can use the authenticationadmin service to login and send a response back with the sessionID ?

Comment: This example works even with the latest identity server. You just have to change the wso2 api libraries which you can get from the identity server.